# DatePicker Inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker, onclick, onclicklistener

Hi i'm new on android development. i got a problem.
I have a Fragment. in the Fragment view i got an Image button for the datepicker. no error was found when i run the Code. but Date Picker dialog is not showing when i click the image button..

Anyone please help me on this.

here is the code:

```
public class Payment05TowMachineEntryFragment extends Fragment {

    public static MainActivity lastCreated;

    private TextView DateDisplay;
    private ImageButton PickDate;
    private Calendar Date;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

    private TextView activeDateDisplay;
    private Calendar activeDate;

    public Payment05TowMachineEntryFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.payment05_towmachine_entry_fragment, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        DateDisplay = (TextView) (getView().findViewById(R.id.selectDate));
        PickDate = (ImageButton) (getView().findViewById(R.id.btncalender));

        /* get the current date */
        Date = Calendar.getInstance();

        /* add a click listener to the button   */
        PickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDateDialog(DateDisplay, Date);
            }
        });

        /* display the current date (this method is below)  */
        updateDisplay(DateDisplay, Date);

    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            activeDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            activeDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            activeDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateDisplay(activeDateDisplay, activeDate);
            //unregisterDateDisplay();
        }
    };

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), dateSetListener, activeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), activeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), activeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        }
        return null;
    }


    protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(activeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), activeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), activeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                break;
        }
    }

    private void showDateDialog(TextView dateDisplay, Calendar date) {
        activeDateDisplay = dateDisplay;
        activeDate = date;
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
    }

    private void showDialog(int dateDialogId) {


    }

    private void updateDisplay(TextView dateDisplay, Calendar date) {
        DateDisplay.setText(
                new StringBuilder()
                        .append(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).append("-")
                        .append(date.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1).append("-")
                        .append(date.get(Calendar.YEAR)).append(" "));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this hope work

```
private void displayDate() {

    Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (OnDateSetListener) new OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
    int dayOfMonth) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       PickDate.append(monthOfYear + 1).append("-").append(
           .append("-").append(year));

    }
    }, mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
    mCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your button click call the `DateFragment` like this

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        DialogFragment newFragment = new DateFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");

    }
});
```

for DateFragment

```
public class DateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
    }
    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        dob.setText(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
        }

}
```

Comment: Hi @gargs why i have error on "show(getFragmentManager(),.." ?